# TImthumb not working for absolute path

Tags: images, timthumb

Tim thumb script is working fine, My issue is with absolute path and relative path.

when i give relative path, i get the output. but when i use the absolute path, i am getting 403 forbidden error.

I would like to use absolute path. Pleas advise

http://crizaze.com/wp-content/themes/joorang/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ami166a-e1295733091216.jpg&h=80&w=80&zc=1

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I always do this with Timthumb:

```
// this is the absolute path
$url = 'http://crizaze.com/wp-content/themes/joorang/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ami166a-e1295733091216.jpg';

// convert it into relative path
$url = str_replace(get_bloginfo('url'), '', $url);

// get the image url, resized by timthumb
$timthumb_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/timthumb.php?src=$url&w=80&h=80";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know what absolute path you are using, but this should work. Of course you may have to do some tweaking to dynamically change the image.

`$absolute = get_home_url.'/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ami166a-e1295733091216.jpg';`

`$timThumb = http://crizaze.com/wp-content/themes/joorang/timthumb.php?src='.$absolute.'&h=80&w=80&zc=1`

---

**UPDATE:**

I took out your foreach loop because get_post_meta will only return one the first value if set to true. I have not tested this out

```
//removed function
```

Also take a look at [Using TimThumb Part 2: External Websites](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/08/timthumb-part-2-external-websites/). Make sure your *cache/ and temp/ folders are set to 755* and *add your website 'crizaze.com' to the $allowedSites array* in timthumb.php. I believe this is your problem for absolute urls.

Comment: "get_post_meta will only return one the first value if set to true" - true, but in this case, it looks like the meta value itself is a serialized array, so it does need to be looped through.

Comment: Thanks goldenapples, I did not know that could be done. In that case ignore my function.

Answer (score 0):

If http://crizaze.com/wp-content/themes/joorang/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ami166a-e1295733091216.jpg&h=80&w=80&zc=1 is your absolute path, then it doesn't work because the path is incorrect. that path reads like this:

http://crizaze.com/wp-content/themes/joorang/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ami166a-e1295733091216.jpg

when it needs to be

http://crizaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ami166a-e1295733091216.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) function to get the path info to your uploads directory. Try something like this:

```
// Where $data represents the fully qualified url, 
// find $relative relative path
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$relative = str_replace( 
    $upload_dir['baseurl'], 
    $upload_dir['basedir'], 
    $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script as below and it worked... Thank you so much for the help.

```
enter code here
```

function portfolio_small_single($id){
    $meta_value = get_post_meta($id, '_port_data', true);

```
$return = '<ul id="small_thumb_lists">' . "\n";
if( $meta_value != ""){
    foreach( $meta_value as $i => $data ){
        if(!empty($data)) {
        $return .= '<li><a href="'.$data.'">' . "\n";
            if(!linkisimage($data)){ 
                $data = str_replace("http://crizaze.com", "", $data);
                $return .= '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/timthumb.php?src=' . $data . '&amp;h=80&amp;w=80&amp;zc=1" alt="" />';}
            else
                $return .= '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/vid80.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="" />';
        $return .= '</a></li>' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
$return .= '</ul>' . "\n";

return $return;
```

}